# Error mkdir desde el servidor

Tags: nodejs, express, servidor, mkdir

Cree un aplicacion en donde se crea una carpeta para cada grupo de imagenes subidas, la cuestion esta en que fui probando mi aplicacion desde el localhost y no habia ningun problema pero cuando subo la pagina e intento enviar el grupo de imagenes me dice: {"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"mkdir","path":"src/public/img/ministerios/prueba"}
el problema esta en que no me deja crear carpetas automaticas desde el servidor.

este es el codigo cuando crea carpetas:

```
router.post('/images/ministerios',async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        const { titulo, info } = req.body;
        const ext = path.extname(req.files.image[0].originalname).toLocaleLowerCase();
        const imageDire = req.files.image[0].path; //direcion actual de la imagen
        let {filename} = req.files.image[0];
        filename = `${filename}${ext}`; //imagen con extension
        let errors = [];
        let obras = req.files.obras;
        const pathFolder = `src/public/img/ministerios/${titulo}`; // direcion carpeta a mover
        const targetPath = path.resolve(`src/public/img/ministerios/${titulo}/${filename}`); // direcion donde estara la imagen
        const viewImg = `/img/ministerios/${titulo}/${filename}`; // direcion para buscar imagen en la vista

        const espacios = titulo.replace(/\s/g,'-');
        ///clases para carousel
        const claseTarget = `glider-info-${espacios}`;
        const claseDots = `dots-info-${espacios}`;
        const clasePrev = `glider-prev-info-${espacios}`;
        const claseNext = `glider-next-info-${espacios}`;

        if(ext === '.png' || ext === '.jpg' || ext === '.gif' || ext === '.jpeg'){
                if(!fs.existsSync(pathFolder)){
                    await fs.mkdir(pathFolder);
                    await fs.rename(imageDire,targetPath);
                    const obrasFolder = `src/public/img/ministerios/${titulo}/obras`;
                    await fs.mkdir(obrasFolder);
                    obras.forEach(async(obra)=>{
                        let extObra = path.extname(obra.originalname).toLocaleLowerCase();
                        let filenameObra = obra.filename;
                        filenameObra =  `${filenameObra}${extObra}`;
                        let targetPathObras = path.resolve(`src/public/img/ministerios/${titulo}/obras/${filenameObra}`);
                        obra.direView = `/img/ministerios/${titulo}/obras/${filenameObra}`;
                        await fs.rename(obra.path,targetPathObras);
                    })
                    const newMinisterio = await new Ministerio
                    ({ titulo, info, filename: viewImg, carpeta: pathFolder, dire: targetPath, obras,
                        claseTarget,claseDots,clasePrev,claseNext }); 
                    const ministerioSaved = await newMinisterio.save();
                    req.flash('success_msg','Ministerio creado correctamente');
                    res.redirect('/');
                }else{
                    await fs.unlink(imageDire);
                    obras.forEach(async(obra)=>{
                        await fs.unlink(obra.path);
                    })
                    req.flash('error_msg','Ya hay otro ministerio con este nombre');
                    res.redirect('/');
                } 

            }else{
                req.flash('error_msg','Este formato de imagén no esta permitido');
                res.redirect('/');
            }

    }catch(e){
        res.send(e);
    }

});
```

Comment: amigo, no entiendo como hacer eso para crear carpetas dentro del servidor

Answer (score 0):

para que funcione la creacion de carpetas desde el servidor hay que aplicarle un parametro de configuracion donde le pasaremos la recursividad a true;

ANTES:
await fs.mkdir(pathFolder)

DESPUES:
await fs.mkdir(pathFolder,{recursive: true});

Comment: ¿Cómo te enteraste de que solo hacía falta eso? ¿usaste algún recurso o fuente de información que pueda servir a otros en caso de que quieran documentarse en más detalle?

Comment: Me entere porque en este proyecto estaba utilizando fs, y mire en la documentacion cuando utilizaba el metodo mkdir y note que existia un objeto de configuracion para pasar la recursividad a true